# Dgrid : How to save and persist column order?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I'm using dgrid with the [column reorder extension](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/dev-0.4/doc/components/extensions/ColumnReorder.md). I have two questions here -

1. I see that after reordering columns, the columns are present in the new order in the `subRows` attrinute of grid (note that I'm not referring to `subRow` here). Is that the best way to get the column order or are there any alternate/better ways to do it?
2. I understand that I will need to take care of saving the column order (or any other property for that matter) and restoring it. When I'm creating the grid with a saved order, what is the best way to do it? Should I create the columns in the saved order or can I create them in the standard order and then re-order them as per my saved order? If the latter is possible, how do I do it?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `subRows` is likely the most consistent way to get the column order.

Regarding saving/restoring, I could fathom doing something like the following. Note that for simplicity's sake, I'm making some assumptions here:

1. You only have a single sub-row (the same approach could be used for multiple, I figure, but you'd need outer loops)
2. Each column references a unique field
3. You are targeting only ES5+ environments (since I use ES5 Array methods below)

When saving the sub-rows, save just the field that each column references (which will make it trivial to serialize):

```
var persistedSubRow = grid.subRows[0].map(function (column) {
    return column.field;
}
```

Then, when creating the grid, have an object hash of your columns in the default order (which you can use to set `columns` if there are no persisted settings), but if persisted settings exist, use that to determine the order by mapping it back against the hash:

```
var columns = {
    field1: ...,
    field2: ...,
    ...
}

if (persistedSubRow) {
    persistedSubRow = persistedColumns.map(function (field) {
        var column = columns[field];
        // Normally when an object hash is specified for columns,
        // field is autodetected from the key.  Converting to array will
        // lose that, so set it within the object.
        column.field = field;
        return column;
    });
}

var grid = new Grid({
    // grid.columns accepts either an object or array as input
    columns: persistedSubRow || columns,
    ...
});
```

Let me know if you run into trouble; I'm shooting from the hip here, and haven't tested the above.

Comment: Thanks.. I see what you are suggesting. I'm also using the `ColumnHider` extension. For the suggested approach, I'm guessing I will also need to persist hidden rows. What if I persist the column settings and then later introduce a new column to the application? How would I account for the new column along with persisted ones? I will need logic to keep track of and compare persisted columns and the default ones with possible new additions?

Comment: Never mind. I was able to achieve what I was looking to do. Thanks again for the inputs.